# plot3d: rgl.postscript adding diagonals unexpectedly

Tags: r, pdf, rgl

I would like to save the plot

```
require(rgl)
C <- rep(1,50)
u <- seq(from=0,to=1, by=0.02)
v <- rep(0.5,50)

my3d <- plot3d(u, v, C,  xlab="u", ylab="v", zlab="C", type = "h", col="blue",   size=2, add = FALSE,  xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), zlim = c(0,1))
```

as PDF, so I used

```
rgl.postscript("my3d3.pdf","pdf")
```

I was expecting to get [image: Expected Output]

but instead I got a picture with some diagonal axes for each square of the cube added:

[image: Actual Output]

How can I get rid of the additional lines?

Comment: I don't see those lines when I try that.  Could you post sessionInfo()?

Comment: @user2554330 I have got exactly the same problem.. Additionally postscript does not add any colors in my case. Snapshot work fine..